# Jupyterlab wont recognize the python kernel

Tags: python, anaconda, virtualenv, jupyter-lab

I try to install the conda environment using the following commands

```
1. conda create --prefix ./envs python jupyterlab
2. conda create --prefix ./envs      after that pip install python jupterlab
3. conda create --prefix ./envs      after that conda install python jupterlab
```

Every time it created the environment without any issue, but in every instance when jupter lab is opened in activated conda environment, the installed python kernel in the environment does not show. Only Python 3(ipykernel) is shown, but it also won't connect.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to install [`ipykernel`](https://pypi.org/project/ipykernel/) in your environment in order to have the kernel show up in JupyterLab.